# Остановка старого IntentService при обновлении приложения

Tags: android, android-service, pendingintent

В приложении используется 2 сервиса работающих в фоне: BackgroundDownloader и Reminder - оба наследники `IntentService`. BackgroundDownloader занимается закачкой новостей через определенное время, Reminder для разового напоминания о событии с интервалом. Собственно по одному работают, совместно не хотят - каюсь проворонил что они выбивают друг друга. Код изначальной установки в AlarmManager:

1. BackgroundDownloader:

   ```
   public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn, int timePause){
       Intent i = BackgroundLoadNewsService.newIntent(context);
       PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

       if(isOn) {
           alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), timePause, pi);
       }
       else{
           alarmManager.cancel(pi);
           pi.cancel();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Reminder:

   ```
   public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn, int timePause, boolean vibroIsOn, String ringtoneUri){
       Intent i = ReminderService.newIntent(context, vibroIsOn, ringtoneUri, timePause);
       PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
       int delay = (int)(SystemUtils.getNextGpTime(context) - System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - timePause/1000);
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, delay);

       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

       if(isOn && delay > 0) {
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
       }else{
           alarmManager.cancel(pi);
           pi.cancel();
       }
   }
   ```

Именно в обоих я и проворонил при создании `PendingIntent` установку `requestCode`. Код обновил и перезалил на устройство (после тестирования на виртуальном - на реальное), и начал думать не пора ли к психиатору, т.к. сервис загрузки новостей остался рабочий из старой версии программы, плюс отрабатывал новый (загрузка может производиться как в фоне, так и в самом приложении по `SwipeRefreshLayout`, хитрая блокировка с паттерном `Observer` не дает одновременно осуществлять загрузку - и при отключенном фоновом мне выдавало сообщение при попытке загрузки в приложении о блокировке). Пару дней терялся в догадках - начал думать в сторону сервиса, после удаления приложения (крайне нежелательного) и залития заново, все отлично работает.

---

Собственно вопрос: как при обновлении приложения и изменении в сервисах можно останавливать программно предыдущие запущенные?

Comment: а еще вам нужно с `API 19` вместо `alarmManager.set()`  использовать `alarmManager.setExact()` - иначе аларм не запустится

Comment: @tim_taller очень странно - в 6.0 отлично запускается... хотя `setRepeat` я уже изменил обратно на `setInexactRepeating` - почему-то сервис хоть и выполнялся, сообщения отправлял через раз (по аналитике видно что сообщение должно было отправиться - а его не было), сейчас полет нормальный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно решение родилось из изначальной проблемы - сервисы выбивали друг друга из-за идентичного параметра `request_code` у `pendingIntent`. Создал статический метод в классе системных методов приложения:

```
public static void stopOldService(AlarmManager alarmManager, Intent i, Context context){
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

    alarmManager.cancel(pi);
    pi.cancel();
}
```

вызов установил перед установкой новых сервисов, старые сервисы после обновления еще работают, но при включении/отключении фоновых сервисов они останавливаются.

Настройки можно отключать в том же методе.

Если кто-то предложит более оптимальное решение - буду только рад.